# How to resolve rounding error in calculated column involving Date and Time?

Tags: custom-list, date-time, calculated-column-formula

I have a custom list in SharePoint with two Date and Time columns, namely `StartTime` and `EndTime`. Now I want to calculate the difference between them, so I created a new calculated column `Length` and entered the formula like this:

```
=INT(([EndTime]-[StartTime])*1440)
```

It should return the duration between `StartTime` and `EndTime` in minutes. But in some situations, the result is off by 1. E.g. **8:30PM - 6:30PM = 119 minutes**. I believe this must have been caused by floating point rounding error. But how do I prevent it? Or should I use a formula other than `INT()`?

**Edit:** I saw this exact same formula [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3), under *Date and time formulas* > *Calculate the difference between two times* > *Total minutes between two times*. But that only added to my confusion, why is something Microsoft used as an example not working as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got a hint from a colleague, the solution is really simple:

Change the formula to

```
=([EndTime]-[StartTime])*1440
```

And then set decimal place to 0. SharePoint will now round off the number correctly.